# How to use patterns to specify variable type as Boolean (True, False) in analogy to x_Integer, x_Real, x_Complex, x_List, etc

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, argument-patterns, data-types

Say I define a function `f[x_, y_]:= ...`, the concrete definition of which is not important now.

What is important though is, that I want `x` to be a real number, and `y` to be a boolean variable, such that it can only have value `True` or `False`.

The former I can do by `f[x_Real, y_]:= ...`, such as described here [in the help for "patterns"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#7301), under "Specifying Types of Expression in Patterns".

However there does not seem to be an equivalent boolean type. Or at least, it is not simply `y_Boolean`.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?BooleanQ]:=...`

Comment: Looks like a good alternative to the answer of Henrik, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be doable with

```
f[y : True | False] := ...
```

Beware that the pattern `x_Real` checks only whether the `Head` of `x` is equal to `Real`; it does not check whether `x` is a real number or not. For example, `MatchQ[1, x_Real]` returns `False`.

Comment: @Hendrik Schumacher Works like a charm, thanks! Also thanks for the warning. I see what you mean. So how would I then for instance restrict `x` to be in the interval (0, 3), but where ideally I would also integers allowed to be entered? If this is not possible, then the restriction to the interval as float would do.

Comment: Then try `x_?(0<#<3)&`. The `_?` pattern means that the pattern matches only if the function following it (here: `(0<#<3)&`) evaluates to `True`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. However it is not the most pressing issue for now. The other one was more important. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, it was the closing parenthesis. Please try `x_?(0<#<3&)`.

Comment: Works now! Thanks a lot! : )

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Britzel "how would I then for instance restrict `x` to be in the interval $(0, 3)$, but where ideally I would also integers allowed to be entered" - you can use `Condition` for this: `f[x_Integer /; 0 < x < 3] := (* stuff *)`.